# POST CURL query with body data

Tags: php, curl

I try to do something... simple, but I'm really locked. I've read a lot of posts here, but nothing works.

Consider this CLI CURL request:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.adalo.com/v0/apps/43b098d4" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -d '{"wp_title": "foo", "wp_content": "foofoo"}'
```

It works. I'm trying to achieve the same in PHP. I've tried this:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

$postData = array('wp_title' => 'foo', 'wp_content' => 'foofoo');

# Setup request to send json via POST.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer XXX'));  

# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

The request works, but the body post data (wp_title and wp_content) it not received by the Adalo's API.

Can you explain me how to strictly achieve the CLI's CURL request in PHP?

Thank you,

Comment: replace json_encode with http_build_query

Answer (score 0):

flag it as post data, as the -X denotes
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

add

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with this parameter, but it dosn't change. My post values are ignored.

Comment: please attach curl_exec and also do a curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: @advancedBoolean the curl_exec just return the Adalo's server response. The request is OK, but just, the Adalo's server do not receive post datas.

Comment: i don't know this API, perhaps you must set it as formdata

replace the application/json with application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and replace the raw json data with query based

field1=value1&field2=value2